# java.util.Map.put(key, value) - what if value equals existing value?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

From the spec: "If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value." I'm wondering about the situation where value.equals(the old value) but value != the old value. My reading of the spec is that the old value must still be replaced. Is that right?

Comment: it will replace and in this way can you "clear" the System.properties() values ;)

Comment: The javadoc is unambiguous: the new value replaces the old one, regardless of whether they are equal or identical.

Comment: @assylias thanks, "unambiguous" is a good way to put it, and now i see that the language doesn't allow for equality checks. the new value replaces the old value, period.

Comment: If they're equal, then it shouldn't even matter -- they're interchangeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a new key matches an existing key, the mapped value will be replaced regardless of it's value, e.g. even if `oldValue.equals(newValue)` is `true`.

I don't think that we need to look at source, or rely on test code: this is explicit from the documentation for [`Map.put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29), where we find:

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)

Comment: This is not the question. The question is : when the key already exists what happens for the value? This is replaced. Even if the value are equals?

Comment: like @assylias, you point to the flaw in my reasoning. the language leaves no room for interpretation. and you didn't use HashMap, which is important to me, because this isn't Python or PHP where a reference implementation is allowed as a substitute for a spec. though, in defense of answers that did use HashMap, this is an interface thing and not an implementation detail, and it would be crazy if the Map implementation were ambiguous on such a point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no check for the value equality, only for the key equality. The object will be replaced by its equal if the key that you specified matches a key that is already in the map.

If a value has been associated with the key previously, that value will be returned by the `put` method. Here is a snippet from the source of `HashMap<K,V>`:

```
for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
    Object k;
    if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
        V oldValue = e.value;
        e.value = value;
        e.recordAccess(this);
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's right. A simple test would have told you:

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = new Integer(1);
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("key", a);
map.put("key", b);
System.out.println("Value is b : " + (map.get("key") == b));
```

Comment: No. The doc clearly says: "Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map". If there were cases where the value was in fact NOT associated with the key, the documentation would state it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your understanding is correct, if equal value existing in `map` for a **key**, it will be replaced with new value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct. You can check this with code like this:

```
Map<String, String> strsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
String myString1 = new String("mystring");
String myString2 = new String("mystring");
strsMap.put("str", myString1);
System.out.println(myString1 == strsMap.put("str", myString2));
System.out.println(myString2 == strsMap.get("str");
```

Comment: And what about other implementations of `Map`? Proof by example is not a proof.

Comment: The documentation explicitly states this is the expected behavior, that if a value exists for that key, it will be replaced and that old value will be returned. But for sake of completeness, the above code prints the same thing for `HashMap`, `Hashtable`, `TreeMap`, and `WeakHashMap`, which are the straight implementations. The other implementations (seen at the [top of the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)) extend one of these implementations or use composition/delegation. `EnumMap` and `IdentityHashMap` also have this behavior. I'd say it's pretty concrete.

Comment: @SteveKuo From the docs: "If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value." And: "**Returns:** the previous value associated with `key`, or `null` if there was no mapping for `key`." Not doing it this way is a violation of the interface contract, so you can expect this behavior in all map implementations.

Comment: Yes I know what the docs say, but your answer is nothing more than testing a single implementation.